# dplyr case when: only 1st instance is affected

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, where I want to change some values in one of the columns.

The column values look like this:

> [1] "soft corals" "soft corals" "soft corals" "soft corals" "soft corals" "soft corals" "soft corals"
>     [8] "soft corals" "soft corals" "..5"         "..5"         "..5"         "..5"         "..5"
>    [15] "..5"         "..5"         "..5"         "..5"         "..6"         "..6"         "..6"
>    [22] "..6"         "..6"         "..6"         "..6"         "..6"         "..6"         "..7"
>    [29] "..7"         "..7"         "..7"         "..7"         "..7"         "..7"         "..7"
>    [36] "..7"         "..8"         "..8"         "..8"         "..8"         "..8"         "..8"
>    [43] "..8"         "..8"         "..8"         "..9"         "..9"         "..9"         "..9"
>    [50] "..9"         "..9"         "..9"         "..9"         "..9"         "..10"        "..10"
>    [57] "..10"        "..10"        "..10"        "..10"        "..10"        "..10"        "..10"
>    [64] "..11"        "..11"        "..11"        "..11"        "..11"        "..11"        "..11"
>    [71] "..11"        "..11"        "sea fans"    "sea fans"    "sea fans"    "sea fans"    "sea fans"
>    [78] "sea fans"    "sea fans"    "sea fans"    "sea fans"    "..13"        "..13"        "..13"
>    [85] "..13"        "..13"        "..13"        "..13"        "..13"        "..13"        "..14"
>    [92] "..14"        "..14"        "..14"        "..14"        "..14"        "..14"        "..14"
>    [99] "..14"

I want to replace the numbers with the preceding value, say "soft corals" or "sea fans" depending on the position

My code looks like this (ah is the data frame obj, cor_type is the column name):

```
ah <- ah %>% mutate(cor_n = case_when(stringi::stri_detect(str = cor_type, regex = "\\.") ~lag(cor_type),
                                     TRUE ~ cor_type
            )
          )
```

This however only changes the first instance of the regex match, i.e, at the 9th row. The rest of the values remain the same. 
I guess I'm wrong in my assumption about how `mutate` works?
PS: I don't want to write a for-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `case_when` is the best choice here. One way would be to `replace` values with pattern (`\\.`) to `NA` and then `fill` `NA`s with previous non-NA value.

```
library(tidyverse)

ah %>%
  mutate(cor_type = replace(cor_type, str_detect(cor_type, "\\."), NA)) %>%
  fill(cor_type)

#    a    cor_type
#1   1 soft corals
#2   2 soft corals
#3   3 soft corals
#4   4 soft corals
#5   5 soft corals
#6   6 soft corals
#7   7    sea fans
#8   8    sea fans
#9   9    sea fans
#10 10    sea fans
```

**data**

Created a small reproducible example to work on.

```
ah <- data.frame(a = 1:10, cor_type = c("soft corals", "soft corals",
      "..5", "..5", "..5","..6", "sea fans", "sea fans", "..13", "..14" ))

ah
#    a    cor_type
#1   1 soft corals
#2   2 soft corals
#3   3         ..5
#4   4         ..5
#5   5         ..5
#6   6         ..6
#7   7    sea fans
#8   8    sea fans
#9   9        ..13
#10 10        ..14
```

Comment: @rangeelo Any specific reason why you want to use `stringi::stri_detect` instead of `stringr::str_detect` ?

Comment: none. sorry, I didn't realize that the function was from stringr package.

Comment: no issues. `stringi` and `stringr` have almost identical functions but `stringr` is included in the `tidyverse`.